# Mass models from FormIt do not render in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Autodesk Viewer doesn't seem to render Mass models that were created in FormIt and converted to RVT. I can only see the level delimiters.

I've tried both https://viewer.autodesk.com/ as well as a basic viewer app I built using the Forge tutorials. This is an important part of a system that I'm trying to put together using a few of the Forge APIs.

If Mass type elements cannot be seen in the Viewer, is there a modification I could do using Design Automation v3 that would make the models visible?

Comment: May I ask you a favor to open this model with Revit and check whether the visibility of this mass element is off in the views you selected? If it is, another thing to check is the [Publish Setting](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Revit-CAR/files/GUID-09FBF9E2-6ECF-447D-8FA8-12AB16495BC3-htm.html), please make sure the views you can see this mass in Revit are selected in the view sets of the Publish Setting.

Comment: If it doesn't work, please consider providing a reproducible case containing the model files and reply to the email you send to Forge Help system, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you also can write a Revit addin with calls of `View.SetCategoryHidden(catId, bool show)` or `View.UnhideElements(elementIdSet)` to change element visibility and run it via the Design Automation API for Revit.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Changing the publish setting made the model render in the the online Autodesk Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Per Eason's advice I added the 3D view to the view set and that enabled the model to fully render in the Autodesk Viewer. This config option can be found under Collaborate->Publish Settings. All models that I imported from FormIt started off with all their views deselected in the view set.